# How can i make .split work to adres the minute and then how can i put a 1 minute interval of two images of the same train

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

the file names are as follow
10_05_30_id24551
10_06_05_id35232
10_06_30_id33539
etc

And the first and the second file are from the same train and they have to be displayed next to each other and thats for all images with a 1 minute interval.

and i cant seem to figure out how to make .split work and to make the one minute interval checker

currently for code i have

```
        var photoPathList = new List<string>();
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        int day = (int)now.DayOfWeek;

        var appFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var fotosFolder = await appFolder.GetFolderAsync("Assets\\Fotos");
        var dayFolders = await fotosFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
        var firstDayFolder = dayFolders[day];
        var allFotos = await firstDayFolder.GetFilesAsync();

        


        foreach (var photo in allFotos)
        {

            photoPathList.Add(photo.Path);

           // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(photo.Path);
        }




        showPhotosEL.ItemsSource = photoPathList;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain at what point in your code you're encountering a problem.

Comment: Please let me know what's mean each underline part of `10_05_30_id24551` . Does it mean hour_minute_sceond ?